# Datatable js sorting not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

As you can see in the screenshot below, the sorting is not working properly.

The **Usage** column is working because of using `file-size` plugin. the **Registered Users** and **Not-Registered** is not sorting properly because there is no plugin for numeric with a percentage sorting that's what I think, so I tried the `aoColumns` with `stype` attr of `numeric` but the sorting seems to be worsened.

[image]

Code used:

```
$("#myDatatable").DataTable({
  "searching": false,
  columnDefs: [{
    targets: "datatable-nosort",
    orderable: false
  }]
});
```

Expected results should be when I sorted Registered Users is:

```
Registered Users    Not-Registered
13.0(87.0%)         2.0(50.0%)
2.0 (100.0%)        2.0(100%)
```

Comment: What do you mean by *not working properly*?

Comment: @Gyrocode.com, it is not sorting properly.

Comment: You would need to elaborate more and give examples of the current results and expected results. *Not sorting properly* is not enough.

Comment: @Gyrocode.com Edited my question.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of DataTables are you using? DataTables will not sort a column numerically if any of the cells contain non-numeric content, other than "-"; in your example, the parentheses and percent signs cause the sorting to default to "html."

Depending on which version of DataTables you are using, it is possible that adding "num-fmt" as the **type** or "numeric" as the **sType** *might* work around this issue.

For DataTables v1.10:

```
$('#myDatatable').dataTable({
  "columnDefs": [
    { "type": "num-fmt" }
  ]
});
```

(see https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.type#Type)

If you are using DataTables v1.9 or earlier, forcing the **type** to **numeric** would be in the following format:

```
$('#myDatatable').dataTable({
  "aoColumnDefs": [
    { "sType": "numeric" }
  ]
});
```

(see http://legacy.datatables.net/usage/columns#sType)